# AMP Content and Domains

Tags: url, canonical-url, amp

apologies if this is known science around the web mastering community, I haven't had to worry about content in a number of years and don't know where to start :)

I'm considering implementing Google's [Accelerated Mobile Pages](https://www.ampproject.org/) for my website.  It's my understanding that I can create **two** different versions of a page -- one for computer browsers, and one for mobile browsers, and then I can use a `<link/>` tag from the HTML page to point to the amp version

```
<link rel="amphtml" href="__MY_AMP_URL__">
```

and in the AMP version of the page, include a canonical link to avoid duplicate content penalties.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="__MY_REGULAR_HTML_PAGE__">
```

Are there any best practices, or known science, on where to put the AMP version of the page?  Should they be on the same domain, but at a different path?

```
http://example.com/foo.html
http://example.com/amp/foo.html
```

or on a sub-domain?

```
http://example.com/foo.html
http://amp.example.com/foo.html
```

or somewhere else?  Or does this not matter in the modern world of white hat SEO and content?

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding of the AMP is absolutely fine.

Regarding your question, I would always prefer a subfolder (on same domain) over subdomain if I need to use canonical tag as search engines doesn't work as good on cross-domain URLs as they on the same domain URLs.

So, I would go with

```
http://example.com/foo.html
http://example.com/amp/foo.html
```

or even

```
http://example.com/foo.html
http://example.com/foo-amp.html
```